# Questions about the Garbage Collector

Tags: java

GC periodically suspends execution while the application is running. It marks the currently referenced object by referring to the method area and stack reference variables. Then the unreferenced objects are removed.

And suddenly I have a question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Object ref = this.returnRef();

}

public Object returnRef() {

   return new Object();

}
```

When there is the above code, the reference to return new Object() is returned and the ref variable is normally initialized, but *if* we assume that GC is executed right after returning, how will GC recognize this and judge it as an object being referenced? (while the reference variable ref is not yet in the stack frame)?

Comment: The stack frames that contain the local variables and recently-returned return values are part of the GC roots, so everything on there is considered a "root reference", so to say. Also that the "stop the world" model you describe in the first sentence isn't *necessarily* true for all GC implementations. Some never stop the whole JVM.

Comment: is that the stack frame itself is considered the gc root? then, how do know that stack frame is related to the heap instance? 
thank you

Comment: The title ought to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the specific case of the Java code you provided, the reference returned by the returnRef() method will be stored on the stack frame of the main() method until it is assigned to the ref variable. This is because the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) specification requires that method results be stored in memory, rather than being solely held in registers. Therefore, the JVM ensures that the object reference is available and can be assigned to the ref variable.

Once the returnRef() method is executed, it will return the reference to the newly created Object, and the JVM will store this reference in memory, making it accessible to the main() method. When the ref variable is assigned this reference, it becomes a valid reference to the object, and the object remains reachable.

In this case, if garbage collection were to occur immediately after the returnRef() method is executed and before the assignment to ref, the GC would still recognize that the object is reachable. It would consider the object reachable through the stack frame of the returnRef() method, even though the ref variable in the main() method has not yet been initialized.

Comment: As far as I know, the data returned from programming languages ​​is stored in registers and then object ref = this.returnRef(); when execute the statement, it actually initializes the variable. 
then Doesn't that mean the ref variable has no reference?

Comment: @user22215161 yes you are right. I have edited my answer accordingly now. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Note that the JVM spec doesn't talk about registers: it describes an abstract (stack-based) machine that an actual JVM can implement however it wants. If the JVM wants to return the return value in a register (as is common in other languages), then it would have to make sure that it's still registered as part of the current stack frame in some way.

Comment: that means the return value is stored in a stack frame and not in a register?  
Is it a special behavior of the jvm? I just found out now..
Thanks so much

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @nischalsharma I believe I downvoted two of your posts (I didn't downvote this one). I don't think the system will let me downvote more. The other downvotes came from other people. I think my comment is accurate and they are ChatGPT, and therefore it's a useful comment to let people know that the answer has a high chance of being wrong. I believe your most recent answers are also ChatGPT, although it looks like you've tried to hide it. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Comment: @DavidW: Agreed. The writing style in this one is totally out of whack with other (recent) answers.

Comment: Related: *[Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)*